# How to prevent ant build changing national characters when replacing characters in xml

Tags: java, android, ant

The problem I am facing is whenever I try to build my app with Ant I need to change some values in strings.xml. The value I am parsing through the `replacefilter` are some swedish national characters. But they are getting changed after the buid is done.

In build.xml I write :

```
<replace file="res\values\strings.xml">
<replacefilter token="@APP_NAME@" value="${application.name}" />
```

in properties file: `ånimal`

in strings.xml the value `<string name="app_name">@APP_NAME@</string>` is getting changed to `<string name="app_name">Ã¥nimal</string>`

I've tried using utf-8 and ISO-8859-1 in both my build.xml and strings.xml Anyone got any answers? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the `<replace>` task, but in `<property file="..."/>`. This is where the value is first incorrectly translated.

Use the following instead:

```
<loadproperties srcFile="application.properties" encoding="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: thanks but the problem was solved. Actually in build the encoding should be ISO-8859-1 and in strings utf-8 so that the xml parser ges the opportunity to do the correct translation.

Comment: Earlier i was having ISO-8859-1 in both build.xml and strings.xml. Anyways thanks Synesso i didn't know the properties file could also take encoding this way